# What's wrong with my texture rendering?

Tags: opengl, textures, processing

I'm trying to render floortiles in opengl/processing3.

Here's my code:

```java
PImage floorImage;

void setup() {
  size(1200, 600, P3D);
  smooth(8);
  floorImage = loadImage("floor3.png");
}

void draw() {

  background(0);
  ambientLight(255,255,255);
  camera(0.0,100.0,-300.0,mouseX-width/2.0,-(mouseY-height/2.0),0.0,0.0,-1.0,0.0);

  for(int x=-20;x<20;x++)
  {
    for(int z=-20;z<20;z++)
    {
      pushMatrix();
      translate(x*32.0,0.0,z*32.0);
      beginShape();
      textureMode(NORMAL);
      texture(floorImage);
      vertex(-32.0,0.0,-32.0,0.0,0.0);
      vertex(32.0,0.0,-32.0,1.0,0.0);
      vertex(32.0,0.0,32.0,1.0,1.0);
      vertex(-32.0,0.0,32.0,0.0,1.0);
      endShape(CLOSE);      
      popMatrix();
    }
  }
}
```

And here's the texture:
[image: tile texture]

The end result, however, looks terrible!

[image: results with artefacts]

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have quad size = 64, but you move it by 32 in x and z directions.I think you have intersections here. Try to replace to this:

```
translate(x*64.0,0.0,z*64.0);
```